# How to use NLP to determine the normal words in the text

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, word2vec

I have a lot of .txt files. I want to train the model which remove bad words from the document(bad word - random sequence of characters). 
For example: bad words - hsA , ubj8 ,t+h ,SSSh ,_^[ ,SVWh ,SSSSSS
normal words : *.exe , copy , write ,write ,ftp.exe

Comment: OK.  So what is your question?  This is a question-and-answer site, so we need you to articulate a specific question.  What approaches have you considered?  Are there any approaches you've considered and rejected, and if so, why?  What properties of a word determine whether it is bad or good?  Have you done any research or reading into NLP techniques?  (You should do a significant amount of research before asking, and tell us what you've found so far.)  See http://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.  I encourage you to edit your question to provide additional context.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably train a classification model to classify normal words from bad words, using character subsequences as features in the words. For example, `exe` can be a feature for distinguishing a normal word from a bad word in your case.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to generate a list of acceptable words along with maybe some regular expressions to check for things like vowels and common parts of speech.

Another way is to count the frequency of each word/token and eliminate the words that only appear once.

Neither of these methods would work perfectly because the definition of the words you want to eliminate isn't well defined.  I think you just want to eliminate low frequency words but that could include some valid words as well.